# what import should i use

Tags: java, swing

I am looking at an old unfinished Sudoku project i did a while ago. I am trying to compile it and i am running into some issues. I think some utilities i used have expired or the import class has changed. In the code i commented my questions. 
`SetVisible` does not work. `Compiler says: Cannot resolve it`. Same with  setDefaultCloseOperation, getcontentpane and setBounds. I dont know why. Are these functions out of style in the new `Java` version?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;//in the compiler this was greyed out
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;//this too
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;//this too
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;//this too
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;//this too
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;//this too
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sudoku extends JFrame {
    public JTextField[][] getTextcells() {
        return textcells;
    }//the compiler recommended JtextField be deprecated? Why?
    public void setTextcells(JTextField[][] textcells) {
        this.textcells = textcells;
    }
    public static final int SIZE_OF_GRID = 9;
    public static final int INNER_GRID = 3;
    private JTextField[][] textcells = new JTextField[SIZE_OF_GRID][SIZE_OF_GRID];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Sudoku frame = new Sudoku();
                frame.setVisible(true);//does not work
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
public Sudoku() throws FileNotFoundException  {

    int puzzle[][];
    String Name = "Sudoku.txt";
    File file = new File(Name);
    Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
    puzzle = new int[9][9];
    try{
        while(inputStream.hasNext())
        {
            String line = inputStream.next();
            inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            for(int i = 0; i<9; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    line = inputStream.next();
                    puzzle[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line);
                }
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }
    inputStream.close();
    Container c = getContentPane();//getcontentpane does not work
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(SIZE_OF_GRID,SIZE_OF_GRID));
    int row;
    int col;
    boolean[][] clean =
            {{true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, true},
                    {false, false, true, true, false, true, false, true, true},
                    {true, false, true, false, false, true, true, true, false},
                    {false, false, false, true, false, false, true, true, true},
                    {false, false, false, true, true, true, false, false, false},
                    {true, true, true, false, false, true, false, false, false},
                    {false, true, true, true, false, false, true, false, true},
                    {true, true, false, true, false, true, true, false, false},
                    {true, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, true}};

    for(row = 0; row<SIZE_OF_GRID; ++row){
        for(col = 0; col <SIZE_OF_GRID; ++col){
            textcells[row][col] = new JTextField();
            c.add(textcells[row][col]);
            textcells[row][col].setText(puzzle[row][col] + "");

            if(clean[row][col])
            {
                textcells[row][col].setText(" ");
                textcells[row][col].setEditable(true);
            }
            else{
                textcells[row][col].setText(puzzle[row][col] + " ");
                textcells[row][col].setEditable(false);
            }

        }
    }

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 454, 451);//setbounds and setdefault.... dont work

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you compiling this code? Swing is still available in the most recent version of Java, 10.

Comment: The shown code looks fine. Under circumstances syntax errors (for instance a `{ }` imbalance) might give erroneous errors, but _deprecated_? Are you using JDK 11 or Androids (no swing) or such?

Comment: @JoopEggen Java 11 will still have Swing. JavaFX is what was removed. See [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/the-future-of-javafx-and-other-java-client-roadmap-updates).

Comment: @Logan IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: @Dees Did you add the JDK to your project?

Comment: @JoopEggen JDK 10

Comment: @Logan yes i think so. It makes me select an SDK before it creates a new project. Is that what you mean?

Comment: With java  9 there came modularization, and swing as separate module (hence javax.swing), as there are GUI alternatives (JavaFX) and non-GUI applications. I have always a `package` statement, and then `modules-info.java` is were the action is. I think you should look there and show it here. Probably a minor thing as using something else besides javax.swing; maybe java.swing.